# Postgresql COPY with text value containing \0 (backslash 0)

Tags: postgresql, text, escaping, psql, backslash

Setup: Postgresql Server 9.3 - OS: CentOS 6.6

Attempting to bulk insert 250 million records into a Postgresql 9.3 server using the COPY command.  The data is in delimited format using a pipe '|' as the delimiter.

Almost all columns in the table that I'm copying to are TEXT datatypes.  Unfortunately, out of the 250 million records, there's about 2 million that have legitimate textual values with a "\0" in the text.

Example entry:

> 245150963|DATASOURCE|736778|XYZNR-1B5.1|10-DEC-1984 00:00:00|||XYZNR-1B5.1\1984-12-10\0.5\1\ASDF1|pH|Physical|Water|XYZNR|Estuary

As you can see, the 8th column has a legitimate \0 in its value.

> XYZNR-1B5.1\1984-12-10\0.5\1\ASDF1

No matter how I escape this, the COPY command will either convert this \0 into an actual "\x0" or the COPY command fails with "ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00".

I have tried replacing the \0 with "sed -i" with:

```
\\0
\\\0
'\0'
\'\'0
\\\\\0
```

... and many others I can't remember and none of them work.

What would be the correct escaping of these types of strings?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried providing a WITH NULL parameter on your COPY TO?

Comment: I have same issue, did you find solution?

Answer (score 5):

Per Postgres doc on [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html):

> Backslash characters () can be used in the COPY data to quote data
>   characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters.
>   In particular, **the following characters must be preceded by a**
>   **backslash** if they appear as part of a column value: **backslash itself**,
>   newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character.

Try to convert all your backslash characters in that path in the field to \\, not just the \0.

FYI \b is shorthand for backslash as well.

So either of these should work:

> XYZNR-1B5.1\b1984-12-10\b0.5\b1\bASDF1
>   XYZNR-1B5.1\\1984-12-10\\0.5\\1\\ASDF1

Comment: I had never heard of \b before so I tried that immediately.  Unfortunately, while the COPY command successfully completes the data that's inserted ends up like:  XYZNR-EE2.2\x081984-12-13\x080\x081\x08S-ASDF1.  And like I stated above, I had tried the \\ way of doing things and that too ends up just like the \b.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

The one you needed was the one example you didn't give:

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```

You want this for all occurrences of `\`, not just for `\0`.

From the perspective of the file and postgres, were trying to convert `\` to `\\`.

In `sed`, `\` is a special character which we need to self escape, so `\` becomes `\\`, and `\\` becomes `\\\\`,  hence the above expression.

Comment: This is the correct answer and was quite helpful. In my case, I converted all ``\`` characters to `/` characters with `sed -e 's/\\/\//g'` because the ``\`` were not meaningful in the input (very very large table) and I wanted to avoid them being interpreted as escapes in any subsequent manipulations. Hopefully that might be useful to others. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that your `sed` command is actually giving you `\\0`?